# Regular expression to remove tags and contents from RSS file

Tags: php

This is the example structure of my RSS file:

```
<item>
 <title>My Title</title>
 <link>http://www.link.com</link>
 <description>The description</description>
 <author>Blah Blah</author>
 <pubDate>Thu, 26 Jul 2012 10:17:15 -0400</pubDate>
 <media:content url="myimage.jpg">
  <media:title>sdafsd</media:title>
 </media:content>
 <position>1</position>
</item>
```

How can I remove the author tag and its contents, the entire media:content tag and its contents, and the position tag and its contents completely from the file using PHP regular expressions?

Thanks!

Comment: What? There are numerous answers on stackoverflow saying you shouldn't attempt to do stuff to HTML using regular expression, but in case of XML, it should be even more obvious. It's XML, why don't use a simple xml reader instead of regular expression?

Comment: I'd like to point out that most people on this site are just parroting when it comes to processing HTML with regex.  There's no reason you can't do so for certain types of scraping.  It's only when you try to match things that require you keep count (like nested tags, brackets, etc.) where you'd be better of using a DOM parser instead.

Comment: My reasons for needing to use regular expressions are a little convoluted, but I basically need to take an existing RSS file, remove  those parts, of it, and then echo it out as if it was the original RSS file.

Comment: Then your question is too localized, @sw333t, and does not provide a good fit for stackoverflow's Q&A.

Comment: @drrcknlsn Ah yes, for certain kinds of scraping it makes sense to use a regular expression. Just not for a well-formed XML file; those are easier to manipulate with DomDocument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer was - rightfully - removed, I should have added it as a comment. Here's an alternative with DomDocument doing exactly what you want to do:

```
<?php

$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>bla</title>
    <link>bla</link>
    <description>A description</description>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <item xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
     <title>My Title</title>
     <link>http://www.link.com</link>
     <description>The description</description>
     <author>Blah Blah</author>
     <pubDate>Thu, 26 Jul 2012 10:17:15 -0400</pubDate>
     <media:content url="myimage.jpg">
      <media:title>sdafsd</media:title>
     </media:content>
     <position>1</position>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
XML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXml( $xml );

foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'item' ) as $item ) {
    $item->removeChild( $item->getElementsByTagName( 'author' )->item( 0 ) );
    $item->removeChild( $item->getElementsByTagName( 'position' )->item( 0 ) );
            $item->removeChild( $item->getElementsByTagName( 'content' )->item( 0 ) );
}

var_dump( $doc->saveXml( ) );
```

Comment: This seems to be a better solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Regex to parse HTML/XML, there are perfectly good parsers out there:

```
<?php

$xml = <<<XML
<item>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <link>http://www.link.com</link>
    <description>The description</description>
    <author>Blah Blah</author>
    <pubDate>Thu, 26 Jul 2012 10:17:15 -0400</pubDate>
    <media:content url="myimage.jpg">
        <media:title>sdafsd</media:title>
    </media:content>
    <position>1</position>
</item>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
//DOMDocument throws warnings when the XML is invalid, we don't care.
//Though in this case, the media: namespace would be ignored because it's not defined.
@$dom->loadXML($xml);
$document = $dom->documentElement;

//Find the elements you want to remove
$author = $document->getElementsByTagName("author")->item(0);
$content = $document->getElementsByTagName("content")->item(0);

//And remove them.
$document->removeChild($author);
$document->removeChild($content);

//Output the resulting XML.
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: I have to disagree with the blanket "don't use regex with XML/HTML" statement for the same reason I did on @BerryLangerak's answer, but still +1 for a good example.

Comment: @drrcknlsn: Regex is not the correct tool for the job. you can shovel a nail into the wall but do you? No, instead, you use the correct tool for the job. Regex can be trivially broken when the expected input varies even slightly, while a parser would remain solid at all but the worst cases of markup abuse. So, no, I don't agree with that comment, and it's also the reason I downvoted your answer, sorry. It's not a blind concept, it's a proven based on personal and community experience.

Comment: Allow me to use a better metaphor.  The "best" tool for hammering a nail into a wall is not a hammer.  It's a pneumatic nailgun.  But if you just need to hang a picture on the wall, are you going to whip out a pneumatic nail gun, set it up, load the cartridge, plug it in, and shoot a nail?  Or are you going to grab that book on the nightstand and smack the nail?  I know which one I'd use.  :-)

Comment: @drrcknlsn: [Let's continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15667/room-for-truth-and-drrcknlsn)

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:**  For flexibility and reliability, you should always use a proper parser like [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for manipulating XML/HTML.  That being said, if you're *sure* that your markup is well-formed, not subject to change structure, and will not contain nested duplicate tags, regular expressions *can* solve problems like this.  But you should only use them if you know what you're doing.

---

You'll want to use [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace each match with an empty string (`""`).  Here is how it could be done for the `<author>...</author>` block:

```
$markup = preg_replace('#<author>(.*?)</author>#is', '', $markup);
```

Basically this matches the beginning tag `<author>`, anything (or nothing) between the beginning/ending tags, and the ending tag `</author>`.

The other tags can be removed in similar fashion.

Comment: @sw333t: As noted, for multiple lines, use the `s` modifier (e.g. "#regexpattern#s").  See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for a description of it and other modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $content = file_get_contents($file_name)

$xmlElem = 'author'
$content = preg_replace('#<' . $xmlElem . '(?:\s+[^>]+)?>(.*?)</' . $xmlElem . '>#s', '', $content)


$xmlElem = 'media:content'
$content = preg_replace('#<' . $xmlElem . '(?:\s+[^>]+)?>(.*?)</' . $xmlElem . '>#s', '', $content)


$xmlElem = 'position'
$content = preg_replace('#<' . $xmlElem . '(?:\s+[^>]+)?>(.*?)</' . $xmlElem . '>#s', '', $content)
```